Android SDK 29: Recent saved file size 0 bytes after device power off
My device has SDK 29 android version. There is no internal battery, is supplyed by 12V. To power ON/OFF we just using wire switch so power off is done by hard cutoff power while Android working.
We have a big problem when we are saving file to internal storage (to app folder). For example, we saved file, and no matter if power off will be done a few seconds later or even half an hour, recent saved file is 0 byte size.
Currently we managed with it by saving dummy file as last one becuase we thought that even if that one will be destroyed, nothing bad happened and exact file will be ok. Additionaly we added file reading process in the and of saving function.
The problem appear rate was reduced but sometimes the exact file is empty too after hard power off.
Here is a fragment of saving function:
                    File task_dummy = new File(file_folder, "dummy_task.dmt");
                    String file = generate_task_JSON_file(task);
                   
                    if (file != null){
                        
                        if(task_data.exists())
                            task_data.delete();
                        task_data.createNewFile();
                        if(task_dummy.exists())
                            task_dummy.delete();
                        task_dummy.createNewFile();

                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(task_data.getPath());
                        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                        oos.writeObject(file);
                        oos.close();
                        fos.close();
                        oos.flush();
                        fos.flush();

                        fos = new FileOutputStream(task_dummy.getPath());
                        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                        oos.writeObject(file);
                        oos.close();
                        fos.close();
                        oos.flush();
                        fos.flush();

                        try{
                            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(task_data);
                            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
                            String file_string =   ois.readObject().toString();
                            ois.close();
                            fin.close();
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                        }

                    }

What is the good and safe method to do saving correctly?
Many thanks.
Lukasz

This question is similar to: Really force file sync/flush in Java. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your main problem is that you use Android in a way it wasn't designed. File-systems needed to shut down before removing power, that is why there is a shut down process in high level OS systemsmlike Android. You you want to omit that you need to change the system/OS not the app.
